# gdbus symbol look up error

Tags: arch-linux, symlink, dynamic-linking, ld

I'm using Archlinux. After a recent update, I find that the gdbus doesn't work and it presents a symbol lookup error:

```
➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  gdbus
gdbus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_string_free_and_steal
```

Then I thought it was probably a problem about the version of library, so I checked the linked library of related files:

```
➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  ldd /usr/bin/gdbus
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd17dd7000)
        libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6b395eb000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6b394a0000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6b3943f000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6b39258000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6b39251000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6b39237000)
        libmount.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f6b391f1000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f6b39156000)
        libffi.so.8 => /usr/lib/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f6b3914b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6b397f9000)
        libblkid.so.1 => /usr/lib/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f6b39113000)

➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  ls -il /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so* 
1195587 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19  3月10日 23:18 /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so -> libgobject-2.0.so.0
1195588 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35  3月14日 18:48 /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7600.0
1195589 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 391208  3月10日 23:18 /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7600.0

➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  ls -il /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so*   
1195561 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16  3月10日 23:18 /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so -> libglib-2.0.so.0
1198392 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32  3月14日 18:44 /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 -> /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7600.0
1195573 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1351064  3月10日 23:18 /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7600.0

➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  sudo updatedb   
➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  locate libgobject              
/home/tidedra/.conda/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
/home/tidedra/.conda/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/home/tidedra/.conda/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/opt/miniconda3/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
/opt/miniconda3/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/opt/miniconda3/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-h4ff587b_1/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-h4ff587b_1/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-h4ff587b_1/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.a
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7600.0
/usr/lib32/libgobject-2.0.so
/usr/lib32/libgobject-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib32/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7600.0
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7600.0-gdb.py

➜ tidedra@ZgrArch  ~  locate libglib-2.0
/home/tidedra/.conda/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libglib-2.0.so
/home/tidedra/.conda/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/home/tidedra/.conda/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/opt/miniconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so
/opt/miniconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/opt/miniconda3/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-h4ff587b_1/lib/libglib-2.0.so
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-h4ff587b_1/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-h4ff587b_1/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libglib-2.0.so
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/opt/miniconda3/pkgs/glib-2.69.1-he621ea3_2/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6901.0
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.a
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7600.0
/usr/lib32/libglib-2.0.so
/usr/lib32/libglib-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib32/libglib-2.0.so.0.7600.0
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.7600.0-gdb.py
```

I didn't find any problem, and there is only the 7600 version, except the 6901 version in miniconda, which I think not related to this error. So what's wrong with my gdbus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what's wrong. I checked my `PATH` and I found that `/opt/miniconda/bin` was before `/usr/bin`, which means when I call `gdbus` in the terminal, it calls `/opt/miniconda/bin/gdbus` actually, instead of `/usr/bin/gdbus`, and as you can see, the version of some linked libraries of miniconda gdbus is inconsistent with others. So I remove the miniconda path in `PATH`, or you can let miniconda not start with terminal, then the problem is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

This problem appears to be related to kernel 6.2.0.arch1-1. I've downgraded to kernel 6.1.12-arch1-1 and I don't seem to be having related issues anymore. In my case the current kernel was even conflicting with the networkmanageer and crashing everything in the terminal

Comment: Library symbols are loaded entirely by userspace, not by the kernel.